# keil v5 STM32F4 - Cannot access memory

Tags: stm32f4, keil, swd

I am using an STM32F407VGT board with an STLINK V2 programmer in keil IDE. I have downloaded to the board a very simple code:

```
#include "stm32f407xx.h"
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  RCC_TypeDef *pRCC;
  GPIO_TypeDef *pGPIO;
  pRCC = RCC;
  pGPIO = GPIOA;

  pRCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 0); 
  pGPIO->PUPDR = 0x11;
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to enter to Debug Session, I cant use breakpoints or see the memory, the command window shows "cannot access memory". I have done the needed debug setup, even I have tried changing the parameters but I just cant´t access the memory on debug, but i do not have problems loading my code. I have also tried on Eclipse/OpenOCD and I also can download the code to the board, but it has the same issue with debugging.

This is my board
[image]

and this is how keil looks.

[image]

Comment: replace your `return 0;` with a `while(1);`. You don't want to return from main in an embedded situation.

Comment: You need to write a Configuration file for you controller that tells what area(Address) of the Memory is what! You need to added that when debugging. I don't remember how you do but I have written one somewhere. Will write more when I get near Home PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I didn´t know it is needed to set the boot0 and boot1 pins to GND/VCC according to the desired boot mode. [Here](https://www.riyas.org/2017/02/quickly-getting-started-with-stm32f4xx.html) you can find the link to the boot mode explanation. If you want to have main flash memory boot, you have to set boot1 pins to GND.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly same problem and I could solve it with the help of [this](https://os.mbed.com/questions/3357/Cannot-access-memory-under-Keil-debug/).

> In the debugger hardware setting window you have to explicitly select
>   SW, otherwise the debugger will try to use the full JTAG interface for
>   debugging. right click on your project root folder > Option for target
>   ... > debug > use: STlink > settings > Port: SW

Comment: I already changed this but the problem is still there. Did you do another change to your configuration? Which board are you using?

Comment: I used `STM32F4DISCOVERY` board that employing `STM32F407VGT6` micro-controller. I think I also changed `Debug > Connect & Reset Options` value other than `Normal`.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.keil.com/forum/59779/-error-65-access-violation-at-0x40023800-no-read-permission/

Hope this helps to write an initialisation file for your controller for debugging!